# Return Anniversary Dates of staff

Tags: sql, zoho

I am trying to query a staffing table I have set for scheduled imports into Zoho. My goal is to query all of the employees that have an anniversary in the current month. Below is the query I would write, but it looks like Zoho does not allow for GETDATE function. Any suggestions?

```
    SELECT
        "Department",
        "EmployeeID",
        "FirstNameLastName",
        "LastNameFirstName",
        "MGR_FirstLast",
        "MGR_LastFirst",
        "StartDate",
        "status",
        "TermDate",
        "wasp_emp_key"
    WHERE "StartDate">=DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-12,0)
     AND
     "StartDate"< DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-11,0)     


UPDTATE - SOLUTION BELOW

SELECT
    "Department",
    "EmployeeID",
    "FirstNameLastName",
    "LastNameFirstName",
    "MGR_FirstLast",
    "MGR_LastFirst",
    "StartDate",
    "status",
    "TermDate",
    "wasp_emp_key"
FROM "Eagle_Employee_EmploymentDates_Status"
WHERE MONTH("StartDate")  = MONTH(CURDATE())
```

Comment: Your query seems to be missing `from` so cannot possibly work. It also looks like t-sql?

Comment: Thanks, and yes it is tsql. I was overthinking it. I edited my original post to include the solution

Comment: There are date functions in Zoho: look up the following page for an example: https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/community/topic/querying-for-a-date-range

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    "Department",
    "EmployeeID",
    "FirstNameLastName",
    "LastNameFirstName",
    "MGR_FirstLast",
    "MGR_LastFirst",
    "StartDate",
    "status",
    "TermDate",
    "wasp_emp_key"
FROM "Eagle_Employee_EmploymentDates_Status"
WHERE MONTH("StartDate")  = MONTH(CURDATE())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).